# What is a word describing someone obsessed with their own appearance in a negative light?

Tags: single-word-requests

Basically, this person would be obsessed with their appearance. They would look in every reflective surface they could find, and remind themselves of their ugliness; but always searching for a new perspective.

I guess as a narcissist would look in the mirror 110 times a day and think, wow, I'm beautiful, a (insert the word I'm seeking here) would think, *you are so hideous.*

Comment: This isn't specific to beauty but self-critic?

Comment: Vanity?  It's not entirely related to beauty but it largely is.

Comment: Sounds like Body Dysmorphic Disorder.  You could stretch that into *dysmorphophobic*.

Answer (score -2):

You could try antinarcissist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antinarcissism